# pyspark error- ImportError: No module named types

Tags: types, pyspark

I'm new to pyspark and python in general, I keep getting this error when I try to import types module:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

I get this:

```
`ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-9-d10338475100> in <module>()
  1 from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
  ----> 2 from pyspark.sql.types import *

ImportError: No module named types`
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information like: your os, which version of spark, whether this is in a notebook/file/ipython repl etc?

Comment: You probably use Spark <= 1.2 which never provided types module.